# How to request the updated data from database without refreshing the page

Tags: typescript, database, vue.js, quasar-framework

I have a q-btn which when clicked will update the *database attribute 'configured'* from *false* to *true*. But the value change in the database is reflected in the database as well as in UI only after refreshing the page. Is there any way that I can update the data without refreshing the page.

**.vue file**

```
    <div class="q-pa-lg c-btn__action">
      <q-btn
        :ripple="false"
        size="md"
        color="primary"
        class="full-width"
        text-color="white"
        @click="sendConfiguration"
        :label="$t('pages.projects.project.template.loadingConfiguration')"
        :disable="!isConnected || !allPeripheralsIdentified"
        data-cy="send-configuration-btn"
      />
    </div>
```

**.ts file**

```
public async sendConfiguration() {
    try {
      this.displayOverlayConfigurationMessage(true);
      this.roomModuleStore.setIsConfigured(true);
      const configurationDeviceService = ConfigurationDeviceFactory.create(
        this.deviceModuleStore.currentNetworkAddress,
        new EncryptDecryptValues()
      );
      await configurationDeviceService.send(
        this.deviceModuleStore.currentPassword,
        this.roomModuleStore.currentRoom
      );
      await this.disconnectFromDevice();
      this.displayOverlayConfigurationMessage(false);
      //location.reload();//reloads page
      Notifier.showInfo(
        this.$t('pages.projects.project.room.configuration.configurationSent') as string
      );
    } catch (error) {
      //catch block
    }
  }
```

**roomModule.ts**

```
//store 
 @Mutation
  private setIsConfiguredToState(value: boolean) {
    this._currentRoom.isConfigured = value;
  }
  @Action({ commit: 'setIsConfiguredToState', rawError: true })
  public async setIsConfigured(value: boolean): Promise<boolean> {
    const room = _.cloneDeep(this._currentRoom);
    room.isConfigured = value;
    await this._storageService.persist(Room, room);
    return value;
  }
```

Comment: How do you know if data is updated only after refresh? Is there a list or something you are looking at?

Comment: the variable isConfigured is set to true after sending configurations and in the UI  the following code is used to display the status.

  <q-item-section class="c-room__item--state lt-md">
        <q-icon
          name="circle"
          :color="room.isConfigured ? 'green' : 'orange'"
          style="font-size: 0.3rem"
        />
      </q-item-section>

Comment: Also I see it in the database that the attribute is updated only after refreshing either the application page or the database refresh directly.